# Given a NumPy array and a many to one mapping array, what is the fastest way to calculate the aggregated mapped values

Tags: python, numpy

I have two NumPy arrays, one containing values, the other maps values from the first to a new, aggregated array like the following

```
a = np.array([10,10,10,10,10,10]) # values array
b = np.array([0,0,1,2,2,2]) # mapping to new index set
size = np.max(b) + 1
result =np.zeros(size)
for i in range(size):
    result[i] = np.sum(a[b==i]) # values mapped to the same index are aggregated
print(result)
```

Which gives:
`result = [20. 10. 30.]`
The above works but it is not fully vectorized due to the for loop, making it slow. From my knowledge of linear algebra, I am aware that I can transform vector b into a transformation matrix and then use the dot function to do this without for loop but that will imply a much larger amount of basic operations than required here, making that approach also suboptimal. Is there a way to do this directly with NumPy? :) In principle, the amount of operations required should be just a.size summations...

Comment: In your example, all the values in `a` are the same.  Presumably that will not be true in general.  Is that correct?

Comment: A few things are confusing: your `a` array has only 1 value (ie 10, what's the point?) and I would expect the output array to be the size of `b` not `max(b)+1`, that is, that for each index in `b` we grab the corresponding value from `a`.

Comment: Hi, yes I have set all values to 10 just to make the sum example easy to follow numerically. In reality, these vectors are quite big and the numbers are different.

Comment: @Max the array `b` contains the index of the result array. It represents the mapping and it will always have the size of vector `a` since it needs to map every element of vector `a` to a new index in the `result` vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the loop with `np.add.at(result, b, a)`.  That will do the aggregation that you want in-place.  See [`ufunc.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html#numpy-ufunc-at) for the general description of the `at` method.